# IE8 on Windows XP is very slow compared to IE8 on Windows 7 and using YUI 3.9

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-8, yui3, windows-xp-sp3

I'm experiencing a very weird problem related to executing JS in IE8 on Windows XP being very slow.

We are using YUI 3.9 as our JS library. We load a form with 315 fields.

I used [dynaTrace Ajax Edition](http://www.compuware.com/en_us/application-performance-management/products/ajax-free-edition/overview.html) to identify where is the time being spent. Here's a screenshot of the HotSpots ([full size image here](http://puu.sh/4Y0cP.png)):

[image: dynaTrace HotSpots preview]

From the screenshot I have identified that the **_enhanceFields()** function is taking about **13-14** seconds because it is looping through *315 fields* and each field is constructed using:

```
Y.Base.create('fieldName', Y.View , [], { properties }, {});
```

Has anyone experienced a similar problem? this takes 13-14s **only on IE8 + Windows XP**. on **IE8 + Windows 7 it takes 5s**.

Windows XP 32-bit and 7 32-bit are using 4 processors and 2GB of RAM:

[image]

Comment: Are you perhaps running IE 8 emulated on your Win 7 box?

Comment: These results are both from identically configured VM's running on the same box (at different times). So we believe we've eliminated different hardware as a cause.

Comment: I have seen similar behavior: JS execution on IE8 is much slower on XP vs. Windows 7.  All other variables held constant - VM images from modern.ie on VirtualBox on same host, with identical VM CPU/RAM config .